# .NET OpenId Library - both Provider and Consumer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, openid

I would like to add OpenId support to an app. It runs on ASP.NET MVC, and I would like to have it support OpenId authentication for users, and also allow users to use the app as an OpenId Provider. So basically I am looking for a good library that can be used as a provider and consumer for OpenId, and it has to be easily plugged into ASP.NET MVC (or at least easily wrapped by a controller and a set of views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stacked](http://code.google.com/p/stacked/) an Open Source implementation of StackOverflow uses [DotNetOpenID](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) which I think also probably SO itself uses...

Though it's built on WebControls paradigm so I think you'll have troubles implementing it with Microsoft MVC.

I know [Grurrah](http://www.grurrah.com/home/) uses a WebControl based Ajax library (Gaia Ajax - my previous startup) together with the Castle project MVC implementation, but I don't know anytig of the semantics. Though Grurrah is Open Source too, so I think you can easily browse the code of it to check it out :)

That means you can use DotNetOpenID together with Castle project MVC library (probably) and you can get to kick in [Ra-Ajax](http://ra-ajax.org) for Ajax functionality (Disclaimer; I work with Ra-Ajax and also Stacked)

Comment: It wasn't so bad getting the provider portion working with ASP.NET MVC. I've not done the consumer portion yet, but DotNetOpenID has an ASP.NET MVC consumer sample.