# google and yahoo login like stackoverflow?

Tags: api, authentication, openid, single-sign-on

I'm researching about Single Sign On (SSO), using google,yahoo and openID account to login in my site.

Some professional can tell me which is method to implement it. API OR LIBRARY to work with it.

Thanks
Nguyen

Comment: which platform are you trying to work on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what language is your site written in? There are several really good OpenID libraries for J2EE and ASP.Net. Check out this other question asked on SO for some .NET implementations.

[.NET OpenId Library - both Provider and Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328079/net-openid-library-both-provider-and-consumer)